# Add pagination in a lightning: datatable

Tags: datatable, pagination

I have received the documentation and I have not found the option to add a page to the table.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example

[image]

Comment: Also, see my [demo app](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/WcZFPJILmOIDzwGDATVD/src/app.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement the pagination yourself, there are several articles that could help you with this.

[salesforce-lightning-datatable-with-pagination](https://www.biswajeetsamal.com/blog/salesforce-lightning-datatable-with-pagination/)

[lightning-datatable-with-pagination-and-search-on-the-client-side](https://salesforceprofs.com/lightning-datatable-with-pagination-and-search-on-the-client-side/)